# How to stream who a user starts following tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, stream, bots, tweepy

So I am trying to create a function that basically is able to use the stream.listener function in tweepy to send a message when a user follows a new person. So basically the function would be in pseudocode of course

```
if user follow new:
    print(¨User has followed{user}¨)
```

This is the code I have right now I am able to stream new tweets that come out of a user using the documentation but I couldn't find anything to stream new followers and such. Any help would be appreciated!!! Thanks!

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
  def on_status(self, status):
    print(status.text)
    myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
    myStream.filter(follow=["(Id private)"])
```

Comment: This is not available as a streaming function, but you can use the Account Activity API and webhooks to receive new follower events.

Comment: @AndyPiper So i looked into webhooks only thing is even that wont notify me when a new person follows another person. Would you be able to provide a example using the Account Activity API suggestion you recommended? Or is their another way?

Comment: No, there is no realtime API to do this for an account you do not own. You could implement it by polling the user followers list and comparing it to the previous run.

Comment: Oh no way that would be sick! Could you send me the exact link of where that will be located so I dont have to search and stuff. Thanks!

Comment: It would be slow as you would only be able to check every now and then due to rate limits (and you may miss followers if they follow and then unfollow in between your polling calls). You would need to use the tweepy `get_followers` method on API v1.1 or `get_users_followers` on API v2.

Comment: @AndyPiper Yeah so i was thinking of doing it where like every 15 or 30 minutes I would check that specific users followers and compare it with a pre maid list or json file that already has that persons followers and if theirs a value missing in it would print out that missing value. Would that work or do you have other solutions? Im just worried that it might get rate limited and that it wont be able to pull up a users followers that have like hundred of thousands

Comment: There's no other way to do it, really - you will definitely hit limits especially on larger follow graphs (it will take a long time to even build that JSON file of existing followers, if an account has many thousands of followers).

Comment: @AndyPieper what would you recommend the time frame should be on everytime it should check the users followers so it doesnt get rate limited and how long would you think it would take.

Comment: You should check the Twitter API documentation for the rate limits.